# How to output first segment title/channel name of entry?

Tags: templating, frontend, channels

For example, I have channel entry https://site.dev/news/2017/test and I would like to output "News" section name on entry page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, it should be as simple as:

```
{{ entry.section.name }}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was so simple. Do you have an idea how can I list section name also at section index page? Tried something like this but without effect `{% if craft.request.getSegment(2) is defined %}{{ entry.section.name }}{% else %}{{ title }}{% endif %}`

Comment: Depends if you have an entry associated with your index page, or just a template file? You might need something like `{{ craft.entries.section('slug').first().name }}`.

Comment: Hey, I just found a solution. It was just `{% if entry.section.name is defined %}{{ entry.section.name }}{% else %}{{ title }}{% endif %}`